# iCloud with Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-4

Do you know how much compatibility iCloud has with the Raspberry Pi?
Can you sync local folders to folders on iCloud Drive?
Can you upload Photos to iCloud Photos?

Comment: Here's your answer: https://snapcraft.io/install/icloud-for-linux/raspbian Hope it helps!